# DevOps CI error for Xamarin iOS build No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-devops

I have created a YAML build configuration for my Xamarin iOS app and have provided the certificate files ( p12 and mobileprovision ) but when the pipeline runs, it fails on the build step for the app. The installation for the certificates pass.

**Note** the build with same cert files and password work fine on App Center

In DevOps I get the below error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(646,3):
>   error : No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to
>   request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com.
>   [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/AwesomeApp/AwesomeApp.iOS/AwesomeApp.iOS.csproj]

Below is my yaml in Azure DevOps:

```
- job: iOS
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- script: sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 5_12_0
  displayName: 'Select the Xamarin SDK version'
  enabled: false

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'iOS_Distribution.mobileprovision'

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'ios_distribution.p12'
    certPwd: '$(p12-password)'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    solutionFile: '**/*.sln'
    configuration: 'Ad-Hoc'
    buildForSimulator: false
    packageApp: false
```

I have tried various different options on the yaml but still get the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should you not set the properties like this:

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
    inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'ios_distribution.p12'
    certPwd: '$(P12password)'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
    inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'iOS_Distribution.mobileprovision'

- task: XamariniOS@2
    displayName: Build iOS App 
    inputs:
    solutionFile: '$(SolutionFile)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    buildForSimulator: false
    packageApp: true
    # This value is automatically set by the InstallAppleCertificate task
    signingIdentity: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
    # This value is automatically set by the InstallAppleProvisioningProfile task
    signingProvisioningProfileID: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)
```

The key bit here is the `signingIdentity` and `signingProvisioningProfileID` on the `XamariniOS@2` task.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, modified and rebuilding now. Lets see.

Comment: That worked, it was an obvious thing which was missed. Thanks for pointing out !

Comment: Easy mistake to make... You also need to watch the build log for it to succeed 