# Azure DevOps build xamarin iOS with signing identity

Tags: azure-devops, xamarin.ios

I have a build pipeline I migrated from the UI editor to YAML. This worked except the setting of the signingIdentity and signingProvisioningProfileID in the new pipeline.

So far I had those 3 jobs in my old, working pipeline:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I created the YAML from those:

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'Apple Distribution MoneyFox 2020.p12'
    certPwd: '$(P12password)'
    signingIdentity: ApplySigningIdentity

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: 'MoneyFox_Distribution_2020.mobileprovision'

- task: XamariniOS@2
  displayName: 'Build Xamarin.iOS '
  inputs:
    solutionFile: Src/MoneyFox.Ios/MoneyFox.iOS.csproj
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    signingIdentity: '$(Parameters.iosSigningIdentity)'
    signingProvisioningProfileID: '$(Parameters.provProfileUuid)'
```

Here I noticed that the InstallAppleProvisioningProfile was missing the Reference name, so I added it again with:

```
name: 'ApplyDistributionProfile'
```

But when I build now, I get the error:

```
iOS code signing key '$(Parameters.iosSigningIdentity)' not found in keychain.
```

I also tried to replace `'$(Parameters.iosSigningIdentity)'` with `$(ApplySigningIdentity)` but it didn't get replaced aswell. How would I have to link those? Or is this part of the build process only supported in the UI pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it as suggested here: [DevOps CI error for Xamarin iOS build No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258438/devops-ci-error-for-xamarin-ios-build-no-valid-ios-code-signing-keys-found-in-ke)

The correct variable for the parameters are :

```
signingIdentity: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
signingProvisioningProfileID: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)
```

Comment: I will in 23 hours :)